# How to import a package with own name instead github address

Tags: go, package, installation

I started studying go, and I have this doubt:

I installed a github package using get, but I still have to import it with the complete address.
Is there any way to install and import it directly with the package name?

Ex:

> go get github.com/package-name

code:

````
import(
      "fmt"
      "package-name"
) ```
````

Comment: "Is there any way to install and import it directly with the package name?" No, of course not. The import path is the identifier which identifies the package.

Comment: If you use a different name, there would be no way for Go to know what package it referred to.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to go about this and neither there should be.

However, if you want to use the imported package in your code using a custom name you can do the following:

```
import (
   "fmt"
   customName "github.com/package-name"
)

func main() {
   fmt.Println("Print something")
   customName.AnyFunction()
}
```